# glFrambufferTexture dynamic color attachment

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to get the following code block

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1, 0);
```

to use dynamic color attachments, (eg. GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, etc...)

The problem is that 'gl_color_attachment' is a type of 'glenum', so the following code won't work.

```
std::string temp = "GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT" + std::to_string(nrComp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color attachment enums are sequential so you can just add `nrComp` to the int value of `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` and cast back:

```
glenum temp = static_cast<glenum>(static_cast<int>(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0)+nrComp);
```

Otherwise you can create an array of the attachments and index:

```
glenum[] attachments = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2,...};

glenum temp = attachments[nrComp];
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently

```
GLenum temp = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + nrComp;
```

works, as GLenum is just an unsigned int, hence they can be added.
Not that foolproof tho, if they somehow(in the future) make it noncontiguous

Comment: ARB would never do this. Their main goal (happily and unfortunately at the same time) is to provide as much backward-compatibility as possible. Especially, they will never change values of constants - once assigned, they are reserved forever.

Comment: It's completely foolproof, because it's defined that way in the spec: " Each COLOR_ATTACHMENTi adheres to COLOR_ATTACHMENTi = COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i."